# Extending and overriding interface properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to extend interface and can't seem to grasp the idea on generics. As you can see I'm trying to add property `auth` inside the `props`.

My code works but do I really need to re-import every properties on the extended interface? It seems that I'm doing something wrong here.

**Inertia-JS Typescript Definition**

```js
export interface PageProps {
    [key: string]: unknown;
}

export interface Page<SharedProps = PageProps> {
    component: string;
    props: PageProps & SharedProps & {
        errors: Errors & ErrorBag;
    };
    url: string;
    version: string | null;
    scrollRegions: Array<{
        top: number;
        left: number;
    }>;
    rememberedState: Record<string, unknown>;
    resolvedErrors: Errors;
}
```

**My Code:**

```js
export type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

interface PropsInterface extends Page {
  props: PageProps & {
    errors: Errors & ErrorBag;
    auth: {
      user: User
    }
  }
}
```

**JSX**

```
import { Page, PageProps } from '@inertiajs/inertia';
import { ErrorBag, Errors } from '@inertiajs/inertia/types/types';
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

export default function Topbar(): JSX.Element {
  const { url, component, props } = usePage<PropsInterface>();
  const { user } = props.auth
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
export type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

interface PropsInterface extends Page<{ auth: { user: User } }> {}
```